# Cannot use env var with Angular

Tags: angular, docker

I'am tryng to set env var in environnement.ts to set url with the rigth env.
**attempt 1** var is not loaded

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL :'http://myapp.api.${MYENV}.xx.test.xx.xx.xx/'
```

--

```
MYENV =test
```

---

```
 **Result**:
    Request URL: http://myapp.api.%24%7Bmyenv%7D.xx.test.xx.xx.xx/xx/xxxxxxx
```

**attempt 2**:
Create environnement.ts for all environement ( test - dev - qa - ppd - prd )
Adding bloc for all environnement

**Angular.json**

```
                    "prd": {
                        "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prd.ts"
                            }
                    "test": {
                        "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                            }
                    "dev": {
                        "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                            }
etc ...
```

select with `build --test` option which environment will be used.

```
FROM node:14.15.4 AS build
ARG  
RUN npm config set registry "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx/api/npm/npm/"
RUN mkdir -p /test/

WORKDIR /test/
RUN npm cache clean --force

COPY ./src/main/frontend/ /test/

RUN npm install --verbose

WORKDIR /test/
RUN npm run build --test
```

build with option **--test** seem's not working **only environment.ts is loading and environment.test.ts is ignored**.

Any idea ?

Comment: It's not at all clear how you're intending for this to fit together. Angular environments are a _build-time_ configuration, just put the URL in the file for the appropriate env.

Comment: Sorry my english is bad :(. yes for adding url in appropriate file but i tryed var to have just one environnement.ts to have url set dynamicly with the rigth env. so the first solution with env var cannot work so what about the second solution with docker ?

Answer (score 0):

add this line in Dockerfile

```
RUN npm run build -- --configuration=test
```

I will put **env** for environnement **test ppd prd** etc for deploy with env var setted in server to automatise deploy without change the ligne manually in the dockerfile

Attempt 1 with var env in the environment.test.ts seem's not be implemented by Angular